# How to get a list of downloads using the Chrome.downloads api?

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've created an extension and I want it to list all of the downloads in the user's downloads folder on a page rather than just opening the download folder.

This is my code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var maxNumOfEntries = 100;

    for(i = 0; i < maxNumOfEntries; i++){
        para = document.createElement('p');
        para.setAttribute("id", ("download" + i));
        var node = document.createTextNode("");
        para.appendChild(node);
        var element = document.getElementById("content");
        var child = document.getElementById("stuff");
        element.insertBefore(para,child);
    }

    var num = 0;

    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

    chrome.downloads.search({text: '', limit: 100}, function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(DownloadItem) {
            document.getElementById('download' + num).innerHTML = DownloadItem.filename;
            num++;
        });
    });
}
```

I've tried various other methods but I just can't seem to get the downloads to appear, any advice?

Comment: What is not working? And also why is there a `text: ''` property when it shouldn't be there?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `text` property?

Comment: What I'm referring to is this part `{text: '', limit: 100}`, the spec does not define this specific field.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant where I create the text node. Can't believe it was something so simple, thanks for your help, it's working now!

Comment: No problem, also fun fact, `.forEach` also gives you the index so you don't need to do `num++`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
I've just realised that the code doesn't load all of the downloads in the download folder, only 60 of them, any idea why?

Comment: It should return at most 100 (by looking from your code) entries, if it didn't then probably you don't have a 100 entries in your Downloads history (in Chrome, not the actual folder).

Comment: I have over 160 items in my downloads folder at the moment, I even tried changing the limit to 10000 but it only displays 60

Comment: When you said *160 items in my downloads folder*, are you saying in the actual folder on your hard disk? Chrome will not look at the actual folder, but it's internal download record.

Comment: Oh that makes sense then haha, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text` property should not be there, which is causing the problem.

```
chrome.downloads.search({limit: 100}, function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(item, i) {
        document.getElementById('download' + i).innerHTML = item.filename;
    });
});
```